# draw a rectangle on top of overlaid images

Tags: matlab, overlay

I would like to overlay two images in MATLAB (`I` and `imagesc(data)`) and then draw a rectangle on top of those. `I2` specifies the transparency pattern in the following code. The rectangle becomes a line on top of the image. Can anyone tell me why the rectangle is not drawn correctly?

```
imshow(I);           
hold on;
h = imagesc(data,[0,1]);    
hold off;
I2 = ones(height,width) * 80;
set(h, 'AlphaData', I2);
rectangle('Position',[100,100,20,20]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since we can't reproduce your code exactly without all the data, here is a complete example with sample images:

```
%# some sample images
I = imread('coins.png');
I_transp = imread('peppers.png');

%# create a gaussian mask for transparency
[r,c,~] = size(I_transp);
M = fspecial('gaussian', [r c], mean([r c]./5));
M = (M-min(M(:)))./range(M(:));

%# show overlayed images
figure, imshow(I, 'XData',[1 c], 'YData',[1 r]), hold on
hImg = imshow(I_transp);
set(hImg, 'AlphaData',M);

%# draw a rectangle
rectangle('Position',[355 220 100 100], 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','b');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I copied your code but, as before, the rectangle appears as a line on top of the image. 

I use MATLAB 7.9.0.529 under linux 64-bit.

Comment: @user499372: could u post a screenshot of what you're seeing

Comment: Please find the image in the following link: [link] http://i54.tinypic.com/xdebg7.png There is a blue line with the correct length and correct j on the first line.

Comment: @user499372: if you copied the example as is, and was still getting wrong output, then I guess it must be a bug (either specific to your MATLAB version, or its a Linux thing). Perhaps you should submit a Support Request to Mathworks...

Comment: @user499372: I had a small typo, try again now.. If that didn't change the result, proceed as I suggested above.