# Reposition images overlayed with imshow - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I had a previous doubt on [Overlaying one image on another gives blue boxes instead of image - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046434/overlaying-one-image-on-another-gives-blue-boxes-instead-of-image-matlab/) which has been solved, but partially.

The images are getting overlayed, as expected, but how can I set the position of these overlayed images on the original image?

Here is the code so far.

```
figure;
imshow(FirstImage);

hold on;
h = imshow(SecondImage);
set(h,'AlphaData',0.2);
hold off;
```

Comment: your question is not clear.. Here are some posts with examples that might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525813, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6604939, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237948

Comment: Maybe you should apply the translation directly to your "SecondImage" instead of trying to change its position on the overlay ?